# Why my fragment does not work

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a ListView in one side and a fragment on the other side. I am trying to make a simple app to figure out how fragments works.
Here is my code:

**Main Activity:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // storing string resources into Array
        //
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);
        //List view
        final ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.questionsList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, adobe_products);

         //final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

                //String selectedFromList =(String) (list.getItemAtPosition(position));
                //text.setText(selectedFromList);

            }
        });

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);
        }
    }

}
```

**Main Activity XML Layout**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/questionsList"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.07" >

    </ListView>

    <fragment android:name="com.example.Layout.MyFragment"
              android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />



</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE: Thanks for your help, I noticed that the fragment is a subclass so I included it inside my activity. But still getting the same result. it stops and doesn't even open. Anyway I updated the whole code that logCat.**

LogCat:

```
    02-22 00:06:50.944: E/AndroidRuntime(2886): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 00:06:50.944: E/AndroidRuntime(2886): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.layout/com.example.layout.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
02-22 00:06:50.944: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-22 00:06:50.944: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-22 00:06:50.944: E/AndroidRuntime(2886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
```

Any idea to make it working?

Comment: +1 for proper formatting even if you are new user :)

Comment: If your class `Fragment` is intended to be the fragment, it should be extending `android.app.Fragment` and you should override `onCreateView`. Also, see this [android developers link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/descendant.html#master-detail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to go through http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

I found many structural and Design problem in your Code , once you go through the above link you will understand it , also download the sample app available on above link page , if still you are not able to do I will surely try to give explanation with sample code. Good luck

Make the following changes in your code

```
1.add the fragment in activity layout like below and don't forget to replace YOUR PACKAGE NAME specified in class attribute 

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        class="YOUR PACKAGE NAME.MyFragment" />

2. Create MyFragment as a separate Class (Should not be inside the Main Activity):

3. Main Activity must extends FragmentAcivity instead of Actvity

4. if you need Listview and fragment side by side change LinearLayout Orientation to  android:orientation="horizontal"
```

It will work

Comment: Thanks for your help. The example in android site was not very clear for me. anyway I did my best to change my code, but still no luck. Have a look at my updated code please.

Answer (score 0):

Hey u forgot to set the orientation for linear layout. By default its horizontal so just add the orientation attribute .

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

in ur linear layout tag.

for the error inflating class fragment just change

```
import android.app.Fragment;
to: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

use onCreateView() to set layout for fragment - 
The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View from this method that is the root of your fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not provide a UI.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I made the changes, still not working. :( Have a look at the updated code please.